# How to get a list of types that my class depends on in Ndepend?

Tags: .net, dependencies, code-metrics, ndepend

Using Ndepend; How can I get a list of all types (*types only from the same assembly*) that my class is using?

*If there is any way to do this other than Ndepend, I'm open to suggestions.*

Comment: I *think* you can use the CodeDOM classes to parse your C# code.  You would then need to examine the DOM structure and find variables and such.  I have never tried this before, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First right click the type and ask for *types that I use directly*:
[image]

Second, a CQL query has been generated for you, and you can explore the result and group types used by assembly and/or namespaces.

[image]

Third, you can refine the query to match only types for one or several particular assemblies:

[image]